# delete text in word document if bookmark is empty

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have the following in a word document

"We are enclosing our office cheque bearing No [chqr] for Rs[chqra]/-(Rupees[chqral] only) drawn in favour of TOM
representing registration cost for the above-mentioned charge instrument and a cheque bearing No [chqr2] for Rs [chgrmat2}(Rupees [amtw] only} drawn in your favour
representing your fees"

[] are bookmarks in the word document.

My VBA codes are as follows:-

```
With objDoc
   If.Bookmarks.Exists(TagName).Then
   Set BkMkRng =.Bookmarks(TagName).Range
    BkMkRng.Text =TagValue
End if
```

VBA will fill all the bookmarks if exists in the above word document.

I would like to use a condition if Range K3= N then delete the following:-

"cheque bearing No [chqr2] for Rs [chgrmat2}(Rupees [amtw] only} drawn in your favour
representing your fees" from the word document.

Your help will be highly appreciated

thanks

Comment: So bookmark that range and empty it if Range K3= N. Simple as...

Comment: if the bookmarks are empty then vba will delete the bookmarks as follows :- and a cheque bearing No    for Rs     (Rupees  only} drawn in your favour representing your fees.What i want if the bookmarks are empty simply delete  the following line :- "and a cheque bearing No    for Rs     (Rupees  only} drawn in your favour representing your fees". I have used the following  condition If  Range K3=N then .Text="and a cheque bearing No    for Rs     (Rupees  only} drawn in your favour representing your fees". Replacement.Text="".Execture Replace:=wdReplaceAll.Unfortunately it does not work.

Comment: So bookmark the range you want to conditionally delete and use BkMkRng.Text = "" when Range K3=N.

Comment: I have added the if condition in my vba it does not delete the above named mentioned lines

Comment: Done correctly it would...

Comment: Ok will try and will revert

Comment: If Range("K3").Value="N" Then . Range(.Bookmarks("drawm").Range).Delete. It causes an error Type mismatch

Answer (score 1):

```
If Range("K3").Value="N" Then TagValue = ""
With objDoc
   If.Bookmarks.Exists(TagName).Then
   Set BkMkRng =.Bookmarks(TagName).Range
    BkMkRng.Text = TagValue
End if
```

where TagName is a bookmark referring to the range to be deleted.